# Connecting Tango device to Windows 7

Tags: google-project-tango

I am having trouble getting my Windows 7 x64 computer to recognize my Tango device.  I have Android Studio installed with USB Drivers installed, and manually loaded Google USB Driver.

The device loads as "USB Controllers - Unknown Device" with errors.  When I try to update drivers and pick a driver from file, pointing to the Google USB Driver I get an error message: "...doesn't contain a compatible driver for your device.  ...make sure it is designed to work with Windows x64..."

I was able to get my Nexus 7 tablet to connect with this driver.

I have tried with USB debugging on and off, and I have tried changing the USB connection to MTP and PTP back and forth with the same result.

When I turn off USB debugging the device sometimes loads as "Android ADB device" with errors.  When I try to update the drivers I get the same error message as above.

Comment: I was able to get my Nexus 7 tablet to work, but not my Tango. It seemed like a Tango issue, not a superuser issue?

Comment: This is ultimately a question about Android Studio, a tool used for programming. I just can't do any programming if I can't connect the device. It is tagged with google-project-tango. Google says this is a forum for Tango development.

Comment: To isolate the question/issue, could you try to run "adb devices" in command line, see if the device shows up?

Comment: I *strongly* vote to reopen this question - this was put on hold by people with reputations in excess of their application of first principles.  Specifically, the tag description includes the text "These early prototypes, algorithms, and APIs are still in active development. So, these experimental devices are intended only for the adventurous and are not a final shipping product"- this text is directly from google and should clearly indicated that Super User is not likely to be able to address an OS that is named YellowStone, i.e. IT AINT OFFICIAL. Tango peeps, please upvote so someone notices

Comment: I was finally able to get my Tango to install (unfortunately with no thanks to the SO community). Long story...when Tango would load (with error) it would show up as Android ADB Interface. Nexus 7 showed up as Android Composite ADB Interface. I plugged in the Nexus 7, set for debugging, and left plugged in. Then I plugged in the Tango - it loaded with errors as before. I then updated the drivers (for the umpteenth time) and it finally loaded as Android Composite ADB Interface, like the Nexus. After it loaded I was able to plug/unplug and it stayed recognized. Problem solved, finally.

Comment: Only a temporary fix. After unplugging both devices for 30 minutes and then replugging the Tango the system does not recognize it - again! Gaaa! Nexus 7 nicely loads again as Android Composite ADB Interface. Tango loads as Unknown Device. I need a little help here Google...

Comment: In the end it seemed like the problem was related to a bad USB cable.  ??? go figure.  Lesson learned: if you are having trouble connecting... try a different cable before going through a lot of other exercises.

Answer (score 7):

First thing you need to check is whether Google USB Driver is up to dated?
Go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html
Download the new driver. Tango Device's driver are included in the Google usb driver.
Unzip the new driver to your folder.

As the problem you mention, you may need to manual install the driver.
Manual Install the Google Usb driver step:

1.Goto Device Manager by Control Panel->System->Device Manager
  Find the "Unknow Device" or "ADB Interface" in "Usb Controller" or "Other devices"
[image: DeviceManager]
2. double Click the Device, it brought you to the Properties windows
Click "Update Driver"
[image: Updatedriver]
3. Click "Browse my computer for driver software"
[image: browser]
click "Let me pick from a list of device driver on my computer"
[image]
Select Have Disk"
Select "Android Phone"
[image]
Select "Have Disk"
[image]
Find the Unzip folder/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf
[image]
[image]
[image]
Click Ok. 
Back to hardware list
Select "Android Composite ADB Interface"
[image]
Click "Next", installing the driver and ignore the warning message.
you are all good.

If it is not working, try removing "Unkown devices" and do again

Comment: Did I not make it clear - I did all of these things...many times and it did not work. This is normally what you would do. I tried that. It didn't work. That is why I am posting the question. I did try using USBDeview to delete all the unknown USB entities and start over. I was partly successful. When I unplugged the Tango and plugged it in again all my fixes went away and I was back to an unknown device.

Comment: When you disable the "Usb Debugging" and re-enable it. what happen?

Comment: Could you add usb Driver using "Action"->"Add Lagacy Hardware"?, It can add the "ADB Interface" driver on Device Manager. but it can't start it . then try "Scan for hardware change", system may recognized a new "ADB Interface", just delete the one you manually created.

Comment: If I toggle USB Debugging on/off - sometimes device manager will show ADB device (only sometimes). 

I have USB Connection type set to Camera (PTP).  I read somewhere else about general Android connection problems that ADB would sometimes only work when the device was set to PTP.

Tried the manual "Add Legacy Hardware" from device manager.
ADB installed, but I get an error saying "This device cannot start (Code 10)". 
I still have a yellow warning in device manager for Android ADB Interface, and for some unknown USB device.